# AppStore: how to login permanently?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, mac-app-store

I'm starting to go nuts already, how to ALWAYS be logged in? I can't stand logging in every freaking time when I want some app...

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a security feature that can't be disabled, and I'd tell you where I read that if remembered, but I don't, so I can't.

Comment: yes, it is a security feature, you can't stay logged in

Comment: lupincho write a post ill select as an answer =/

Comment: Pinging @lupincho — holms, you need to `@ping` users, otherwise they don't get a reply.

Comment: @holms, the answer wasn't originally by me, it was by The Electric Muffin, I hust confirmed it; also check slhck's suggestion about pinging The Electric Muffin if you want this posted as an answer

Comment: @ping The Electric Muffin write answer i'll confirm it

Comment: Yes! this is so annoying, especially since you have to be logged in even to download something that is free!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is solved. In current iOS versions we can store appstore credentials for certain amount of time. Especially this is great for free apps, iOS offers to store password for you after first request of credentials